# Keyboard Shortcut to Toggle Between Modules in Excel VBA Editor

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I am working with multiple modules in Excel's Visual Basic editor. Is there a shortcut to toggle between different modules?

Comment: Does `ctrl`+`tab` not work?

Comment: I don't think there is a single shortcut to toggle. But you can press CTRL+R to focus on the project explorer, then up/down and enter to select and load the module you want.

Comment: If you're in windows Burgi is correct